# Problema con un slideshow

Tags: javascript

he copiado un código de un slideshow (adjunto mas adelante los archivos) y lo he modificado para que no salgan los números de pagina pero en su lugar sale un rectángulo negro y no consigo eliminarlo, espero que me puedan echar una mano.

Adjunto imagen donde se puede ver el rectángulo negro abajo a la derecha.
https://i.postimg.cc/fL3WSCKm/slideshow.png

De entrada aviso que no entiendo casi nada, por no decir nada de javascript. Ruego a los administradores que en caso de no encajar en esta categoría lo muevan a la categoría correcta.

Codigo Javascript
https://pastebin.com/Rx4GnvJk

Codigo PHP
https://pastebin.com/XNyWMirs

Codigo CSS
https://pastebin.com/kC2sJW1m

Gracias de antemano.

Necesito solo un simple slideshow que muestre una imagen tras de otra con un efecto de "desvanecimiento" de las imágenes pero todo lo que encuentro muestra números de pagina y/o botones de avanzar y retroceder. Sin limite de imagines (quiero que aparezcan mínimo de 50 imágenes)

Answer (score 0):

El problema no era del javascript, si no del css, eliminando donde pone

```
.slidesjs-navigation{
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:13.5px 20px;
    float:right;
}
```

desaparece el rectangulo.